# Qt c++ application mouse click and touch different behavior

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

Qt5 c++ application. Works in Linux Debian. The device uses a touch screen.

There is following problem: when you click the `qLineEdit` with the mouse, the field is selected and the cursor appears, and when you touch the touch screen, the blinking cursor does not appear.
Moreover, if you click on the input field, then in the future, even after losing focus, it is also activated by touch, as well as by click.

function to activate the input field:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_clicked()
{
    
    ui->lineEdit_2->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;border-radius: 4px;");
    ui->lineEdit->setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid #5f5f5f;border-radius: 4px;");
    
    qDebug() << "curient: " << ui->widget_key_board->geometry();
    curient_field = ui->lineEdit;
    if(ui->widget_key_board->geometry() == QRect(ui->widget_key_board->geometry().left(),animation_constant_2,ui->widget_key_board->width(),ui->widget_key_board->height()))
    {
        qDebug() << "animation call";
        MainWindow::animation();
        animationGroup->start();
    }
}
```

[image]

I've tried setting the cursor with `setCursorPosition()` and emulating a click, to no avail.

for push to field

```
void MainWindow::on_btn_x_clicked()
{
    curient_field->setFocus();
    curient_field->insert(ui->btn_x->text());
}
void MainWindow::on_btn_c_clicked()
{
    curient_field->setFocus();
    curient_field->insert(ui->btn_c->text());
}
```

[enter image description here][1]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question? What do you expect to happen? Please [edit] and tell us. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the code you use for creating the inputs for SSID & Password.